# jquery resizable changing css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the jQuery `resizable` function on some divs on a page I'm working on. I also have some events that trigger an element to not be resizable anymore so I'm calling `.resize('destroy');`

however it seems like changing an element from resizable to not resizable is changing the css of the element and making it act strange. What css changes take place when an element becomes resizable?

Comment: Please share a fiddle reproducing your problem. It'll be much easier to understand what is happening.

Comment: ok give me a couple of minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you apply `.resizable()` 
your element takes `position: relative;`

Answer (score 0):

When you call the resizable function on an element, you are adding classes to the element eg:

```
ui-widget-content ui-resizable
```

The css file which comes with the plugin has got style attributes referring to these new classes which essentially adds a corner image. This is the only thing I can see that changes visually in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8beLba19/1/).